# Performance analysis tool for Tensorflow

Tags: framework, performance-analysis

I am currently working on a school project that consists on analyzing the performance of Machine Learning models in order to assess their scalability and spot potential bottlenecks in their framework.

I am looking for a performance analysis tool that works for Python programs written using Tensorflow's library. My system is running 4 CPU's [AMD EPYC 7451](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-epyc-7451) on "Buster" version of Debian. I am willing to visualize the execution trace in order to understand the program's performance.

Comment: Lock contention and lack of parallelism will be solved by various different tools. Same for the others. So, please ask a question for each, specifying the OS (choose one) and language (choose one) and ML libraries for each. Thanks! Also, please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: The question was edited @NicolasRaoul. Thanks for the review.

Comment: "visualize the execution trace" is still extremely vague.